# Filter rows using multiple conditions to create a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A Code': ['123', '234', '345', '234', '789', '345'],
    'B Code': ['345', '123', '234', '123', '567', '567'],
    'C Code': ['678', '123', '456', '234', '321', '789'],
    'X Code': ['987', '765', '432', '876', '321', '765'],
    'Y Code': ['765', '876', '987', '765', '432', '543'], 
    'H Code 1': ['EF', 'AB', 'GH', 'CD', 'GH', 'CD'],
    'H Code 2': ['AB', 'CD', 'CD', 'AB', 'CD', 'GH']
})

    A Code  B Code  C Code  X Code  Y Code  H Code 1  H Code 2
0    123     345     678     987     765      EF         AB
1    234     123     123     765     876      AB         CD
2    345     234     456     432     987      GH         CD
3    234     123     234     876     765      CD         AB
4    789     567     321     321     432      GH         CD
5    345     567     789     765     543      CD         GH
```

The following conditions indicate that a row represents an apple:

```
1) H Code of 'AB' or 'EF'
OR
2) X or Y Code of '765'
OR
3) A, B or C Code of '123' and X or Y Code of '987'
OR
4) A, B or C Code of '234' or '345' and X or Y code of 876
```

I want to create a column that labels rows that meet any of the conditions above as apples and those that don't as bananas. So something like this:

```
    A Code  B Code  C Code  X Code  Y Code  H Code 1  H Code 2  Fruit
0    123     345     678     987     765      EF         AB     apple
1    234     123     123     765     876      AB         CD     apple
2    345     234     456     432     987      GH         CD     banana
3    234     123     234     876     765      CD         AB     apple
4    789     567     321     321     432      GH         CD     banana
5    345     567     789     765     543      CD         GH     apple
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use individual boolean masks for each condition and group them according your operators:

```
m1 = df[['H Code 1', 'H Code 2']].isin(['AB', 'EF']).any(axis=1)
m2 = df[['X Code', 'Y Code']].eq('765').any(axis=1)
m3 = df[['A Code', 'B Code', 'C Code']].eq(123).any(axis=1)
m4 = df[['X Code', 'Y Code']].eq('987').any(axis=1)
m5 = df[['A Code', 'B Code', 'C Code']].isin([234, 345]).any(axis=1)
m6 = df[['X Code', 'Y Code']].eq('876').any(axis=1)
m = m1 | m2 | (m3 & m4) | (m5 & m6)

df['Fruit'] = np.where(m, 'apple', 'banana')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  A Code B Code C Code X Code Y Code H Code 1 H Code 2   Fruit
0    123    345    678    987    765       EF       AB   apple
1    234    123    123    765    876       AB       CD   apple
2    345    234    456    432    987       GH       CD  banana
3    234    123    234    876    765       CD       AB   apple
4    789    567    321    321    432       GH       CD  banana
5    345    567    789    765    543       CD       GH   apple
```